# Change text color in haml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

I'm developing a ruby on rails interface, and I need to change the text color of the label of a form written in haml.
My code looks like that:

```
%li
 %label  NAME:
   %input{:type=>'text', :name=>'user[name]', :value => params[:name],  :maxlength=> 10,}
```

Please tell me how can I apply a blue color over the label NAME.

Answer (score 1):

In your css you can do:

```
label {
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

If the form has a class or id:

```
#yourformid label {
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

It's just basic CSS. It doesn't matter that it's written with HAML.